# PHP: Counting based on a date day range

Tags: php

Okay, how do I explain this. Let say I have an array of numbers/days.

```
$days = array(31,24,08,14,17);
```

Now I have 4 cycles with particular day range.

- Cycle 1: 23-01
- Cycle 2: 02-08
- Cycle 3: 09-15
- Cycle 4: 16-22

So now I want to count how many of the value from the days array fall on each cycle.

Cycle 1 will count as 2 since 31 and 24 falls within 23-01
Cycle 2 will count 1 (08)
Cycle 3 will count 1 (14)
Cycle 4 will count 1 (17)

The numbers are from days of a given date and I just have to count the days that fall in. I already can count from cycle 2-4 but having problem with cycle 1.

```
$cycle1 = 0;
$cycle2 = 0;
$cycle3 = 0;
$cycle4 = 0;

$days = array(31,24,08,14,17);

foreach ($days as $day)
{
    if ($day >= 23 && $day <= 01)
    {
        $cycle1++;
    }

    if ($day >= 02 && $day <= 08)
    {
        $cycle2++;
    }

    if ($day >= 09 && $day <= 15)
    {
        $cycle3++;
    }

    if ($day >= 16 && $day <= 22)
    {
        $cycle4++;
    }

}
```

Thanks, hope someone can shed some light on how to do it via only date('d',strtotime(datestring)); range.

Comment: Please enable proper PHP error reporting. This should have given you “Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in /in/msTqX on line 8” And the reason for that, is that `08` is not a valid _octal_ number. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Actually I just printed them here as it is, on my actual code it is using variables: if ($current_period >= $start && $current_period <= $end ) so it would be easier to get the logic

Comment: Please don’t ask us to debug code that is significantly different from what you are actually using. [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$days = array(31,24,14,17,1,16);
/*
Cycle 2: 02-08 =>() = 0
Cycle 3: 09-15 =>(14) = 1 
Cycle 4: 16-22 =>(17,16) = 2
Cycle 1: 23-01 =>(31,24,1) = 3
*/
$cycle1 = $cycle2 = $cycle3 = $cycle4 = 0;

foreach ($days as $day)
{
    if($day >= 23)
        $cycle1++;

    elseif($day >= 16)
        $cycle4++;

    elseif($day >= 9)
        $cycle3++;

    elseif($day >= 2)
        $cycle2++;

    else
        $cycle1++;
}
echo "cycle1=$cycle1<br>cycle2=$cycle2<br>cycle3=$cycle3<br>cycle4=$cycle4<br>";
```